# Why Process Builder doesn't work on Delete Scenario?

Tags: process-builder

As most of the time we have to think of requirement to accomplished using out-of-Box feature like e.g process builder which we think of an alternative to trigger, but suppose I have to handle scenario of Delete using Process Builder then there is limitation!(e.g calculation of roll-up on Delete) so I am curious about what is that limitation because of which Delete scenario is not handled in Process Builder.

Comment: can't think of any valid restrictions in the platform. vote up this idea to get it above the point threshold.. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjtIAAS

Comment: Yeah Idea is there I am aware of that Thanks for the response, I am curious about what is that limitation because of which Delete scenario is not handled in Process Builder.

Answer (score 2):

The "why" is a question for Salesforce product managers. I'm not sure the public knows of why they have this limitation.

Do please vote for these ideas:

[Fire Workflow Rules for Deleted Records](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwwmAAA)

[Fire Process Builder for Deleted Records](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LlbtQAC)

Comment: To save you some clicks, the Ideas mentioned above have been merged into [Workflow, Visual Workflow, Process Builder Triggered on Delete](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlPBAA0)